# Angular2 select component does not properly bind value while having observable ngModel

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I challenge a problem with displaying currently selected value on  component. NgModel of that is observable which changed in runtime.

```
  <select [ngModel]="selectedVersion$ | async" (ngModelChange)="changeVersion($event)" class="dropdown">
    <option *ngFor="let version of versions" [ngValue]="version">{{version.fullName}}</option>
  </select>
```

selectedVersion$ is ngRedux value of type Observable:

```
selectedLanguage$: Observable<string>;

constructor(
    private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>,
    private actions: TopbarActions,
    private cookieService: CookieService) {
    this.selectedVersion$ = ngRedux.select<Version>('version'); 
}

ngOnInit(): void {
     this.subscription.add(this.selectedVersion$.subscribe(version => {
         this.checkExistence(version, this.versionSelectionCallback, this);
}));
```

When I dispatch new version - selectedVersion$ variable is updated:

```
changeVersion(version: Version): void {
    this.ngRedux.dispatch(this.actions.setVersion(version));
    this.cookieService.set("rcm-version", JSON.stringify(version), 5, "/");
}
```

(I've changed it on view template by displaying with async and json pipes):

```
{{selectedVersion$ | async | json}}
```

But selected value on  component is not updated. 
I've tried to force change detection cycle, but it also does not work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is versions, in 'let version of versions'?

Comment: It is an Array<Version>

Comment: If you try to get the Observable from the ngRedux again, just after dispatching it, is it updated? Try subscribing to it at the ngOnInit, and debugging value changes. Would be good if you could provide a Plunker of your code.